# Changing accordion so only closes when header is clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've got a simple few accordions that are made interactive with vanilla JS. They open perfectly, however once they're open if you click anywhere in the div then they close. I know this is happening because of the following line:

```
var allPanelElems = accordionElem.querySelectorAll(".checkout-accordion");
```

However, I'm scratching my head as to how to rephrase the JavaScript so they only close when you click on the accordion header, and not the accordion body too.

Here's the full code:

```js
function initAccordion(accordionElem){

  function handlePanelClick(event){
      showPanel(event.currentTarget);
  }

  function showPanel(panel){
     let expandedPanel = accordionElem.querySelector(".active");
     if (panel === expandedPanel){
         expandedPanel.classList.remove("active");
     } else {
       panel.classList.add("active");
     }

  }
  var allPanelElems = accordionElem.querySelectorAll(".checkout-accordion");
  for (var i = 0, len = allPanelElems.length; i < len; i++){
       allPanelElems[i].addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick);
  }
  showPanel(allPanelElems[0])
}
initAccordion(document.getElementById("checkout-details-container"));
```

```css
.checkout-details-section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#checkout-details-container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.checkout-accordion {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.accordion-header {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-dropdown {
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.accordion-dropdown label {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion-dropdown input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Start of checkout details accordion functionality */

#checkout-details-container .accordion-dropdown {
  display: none;
}

#checkout-details-container .active .accordion-dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
  <!-- Checkout Details Section -->

  <section class="checkout-details-section">
    <div id="checkout-details-container">
      <div class="checkout-accordion active"> <!-- Personal Details -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Personal Details</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
      <label for="fullName">Full name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullName" value="">
      <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="">
      <label for="phone">Enter your phone number</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Shipping Address -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Shipping Address</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="firstLine">House number and street name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstLine" value="">
          <label for="secondLine">Enter your local area</label>
          <input type="text" name="secondLine" value="">
          <label for="city">Enter your city</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" value="">
          <label for="region">Enter your region</label>
          <input type="text" name="region" value="">
          <label for="postcode">Enter your postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="postcode" value="">
          <label for="country">Enter your country</label>
          <input type="text" name="country" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Billing Address -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Billing Address</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="billingFirst">House number and street name</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingFirst" value="">
          <label for="billingSecond">Enter your local area</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingSecond" value="">
          <label for="billingCity">Enter your city</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingCity" value="">
          <label for="billingRegion">Enter your region</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingRegion" value="">
          <label for="billingPostcode">Enter your postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingPostcode" value="">
          <label for="billingCountry">Enter your country</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingCountry" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Payment Details -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Payment Details</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="cardNumber">Enter your card number</label>
          <input type="text" name="cardNumber" value="">
          <label for="expiryDate">Enter your card's expiry date</label>
          <input type="date" name="expiryDate" placeholder="DD / YYYY" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" value="">
          <label for="csv">Enter your card's CSV</label>
          <input type="text" name="csv" placeholder="123" require pattern="[0-9]{4}" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Weirdly too, it only happens on the *second* click on the accordion, not the first. There's another weird bug which means if two accordions are open, the first accordion won't close on click until you close the second. If anyone has any idea why that's happening, an answer would be great too.

Thanks, hopefully my questions clear.

Answer (score 0):

You could conditionally handle the panel click event by checking if it's coming from the header (as you want). Your JavaScript should be looking somewhat like:

```js
function initAccordion(accordionElem) {
      function handlePanelClick(event) {
        // if the event is coming from the header then show panel
        if (event.path[0].classList[0] === "accordion-header"){
              showPanel(event.currentTarget);
        }
      }
    
      function showPanel(panel) {
        let expandedPanel = accordionElem.querySelector(".active");
        if (panel === expandedPanel) {
          expandedPanel.classList.remove("active");
        } else {
          panel.classList.add("active");
        }
      }
      var allPanelElems = accordionElem.querySelectorAll(".checkout-accordion");
      for (var i = 0, len = allPanelElems.length; i < len; i++) {
        allPanelElems[i].addEventListener("click", handlePanelClick);
      }
      showPanel(allPanelElems[0]);
    }
    
    initAccordion(document.getElementById("checkout-details-container"));
```

```css
.checkout-details-section {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#checkout-details-container {
  height: 90%;
  width: 90%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.checkout-accordion {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  margin: 50px 0;
}

.accordion-header {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-around;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.accordion-dropdown {
  height: auto;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 30px 0;
}

.accordion-dropdown label {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 10px 0;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.accordion-dropdown input {
  height: 40px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 20px 0;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #999;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
}

/* Start of checkout details accordion functionality */

#checkout-details-container .accordion-dropdown {
  display: none;
}

#checkout-details-container .active .accordion-dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
 <!-- Checkout Details Section -->

  <section class="checkout-details-section">
    <div id="checkout-details-container">
      <div class="checkout-accordion active"> <!-- Personal Details -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Personal Details</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
      <label for="fullName">Full name</label>
      <input type="text" name="fullName" value="">
      <label for="email">Enter your email</label>
      <input type="email" name="email" value="">
      <label for="phone">Enter your phone number</label>
      <input type="tel" name="phone" value="">
      </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Shipping Address -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Shipping Address</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="firstLine">House number and street name</label>
          <input type="text" name="firstLine" value="">
          <label for="secondLine">Enter your local area</label>
          <input type="text" name="secondLine" value="">
          <label for="city">Enter your city</label>
          <input type="text" name="city" value="">
          <label for="region">Enter your region</label>
          <input type="text" name="region" value="">
          <label for="postcode">Enter your postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="postcode" value="">
          <label for="country">Enter your country</label>
          <input type="text" name="country" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Billing Address -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Billing Address</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="billingFirst">House number and street name</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingFirst" value="">
          <label for="billingSecond">Enter your local area</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingSecond" value="">
          <label for="billingCity">Enter your city</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingCity" value="">
          <label for="billingRegion">Enter your region</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingRegion" value="">
          <label for="billingPostcode">Enter your postcode</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingPostcode" value="">
          <label for="billingCountry">Enter your country</label>
          <input type="text" name="billingCountry" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="checkout-accordion"> <!-- Payment Details -->
        <div class="accordion-header">
          <h1>Payment Details</h1>
          <i class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="accordion-dropdown">
          <label for="cardNumber">Enter your card number</label>
          <input type="text" name="cardNumber" value="">
          <label for="expiryDate">Enter your card's expiry date</label>
          <input type="date" name="expiryDate" placeholder="DD / YYYY" required pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}" value="">
          <label for="csv">Enter your card's CSV</label>
          <input type="text" name="csv" placeholder="123" require pattern="[0-9]{4}" value="">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not working - appreciate the response though.

Comment: Did you test the snippet on here? @JonNicholson

Comment: Hi - I did, it comes up with an immediate 'script' error.